# Getting exception while establishing Trust Line

Tags: horizon, trustline, python-sdk

I am working on Stellar Python SDK after a year. When I ran my old script I got the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'opts'
```

The code given below:

```
from stellar_base.asset import Asset
from stellar_base.horizon import horizon_testnet
from stellar_base.keypair import Keypair
from stellar_base.memo import TextMemo
from stellar_base.operation import ChangeTrust, Payment
from stellar_base.transaction import Transaction
from stellar_base.transaction_envelope import TransactionEnvelope as Te
def opr_change_trust(asset_object, receiver_address, receiver_seed, horizon):
    # Operation Object
    op = ChangeTrust({
        'source': receiver_address,
        'asset': asset_object,
        'limit': '5000'
    })

    print('Establishing trust-line for the account {}. Please wait!!'.format(receiver_address))

    # Getting the next sequence of the address
    sequence = horizon.account(receiver_address).get('sequence')

    # Create Text Memo
    msg = TextMemo('Change Trust Operation')

    # construct Tx
    tx = Transaction(
        source=receiver_address,
        opts={
            'sequence': sequence,
            'memo': msg,
            'operations': [
                op,
            ],
        },
    )
    # xdr = tx.xdr()
    # deccoded_xdr = tx.to_xdr_object()
    # print(deccoded_xdr)

    # Get reference of receiving account
    receiving_account = Keypair.from_seed(receiver_seed)
    # build envelope
    envelope = Te(tx=tx, opts={"network_id": "TESTNET"})
    envelope.sign(receiving_account)

    xdr_envelope = envelope.xdr()
    # Submit the signed transaction to Horizon server.
    response = horizon.submit(xdr_envelope)
    print(response)

    if 'result_xdr' in response:
        return True
    else:
        print('Things go Fishy while opr_change_trust')
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is available here: https://stellar-base.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#transaction

The transaction object is constructed like so:

```
Transaction(source, sequence, time_bounds=None, memo=None, fee=None, operations=None)
```

Passing in opts as a list seems to be causing the issue.